# Keycloak token validation flow

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

[image]

When a request with the bearer token hits a microservice, does microservice talk to keycloak to validate the token for each request?

Is traffic "Step 5" configurable via keycloak adapter?

Answer (score 2):

No, that would make too many requests. In initialization phase microservice loads public key and signing algorithm from Keycloak’s well known config page. On each request microservice checks the signature of the bearer token.
Access token lifespan should not be too long and that is how you force your frontend to periodically go to Keycloak and refresh the bearer.

Comment: and this is done by making the microservice a "bearer only" client, thus token validation is done offline without going to KC right?

Comment: No and yes. No, bearer only client is something else. Yes, token validation is done offline without going to Keycloak.

Comment: well, I made that assumption from here https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-February/013005.html

Comment: If you look at the picture above bearer only client would be another service that is called by "Secured microservice". The downside described on your link is the problem with offline validation. It is not limited to bearer only clients.

Comment: oh, definitely, my bad, he's calling the microservice directly. So what kind of client is the microservice in this case (picture)? If it's public, it will go to Keycloak to make sure token wasn't invalidated by a logout, like from a call to the logout endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your microservice, every time you send a request to an api after adding the token in the logs you will see "Loaded URLs from http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{realm-name}/.well-known/openid-configuration". Upon clicking this link you will see that there are a set of URLs present here, endpoints for token generation, userinfo etc.,there are endpoints for getting the certs and signing keys as well via which the signing key of the token is verified.
(This will only happen if keycloak properties are defined in application.properties/application.yml)

Step 5 will happen on using Keycloak adapter (Choice of adapter given in keycloak documentation)